# launch an animation when the angular server is launched

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I would like to launch a Netflix animation after my server has started. What I tried is to play with the setTimeout but it does not work, do you have an idea? I will not publish the html and css code because it is too long.

you can find the code for the animation in question by following this link:
https://codepen.io/claudio_bonfati/pen/mdryxPv

Thank you.

**AppComponent**

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-page-film',
templateUrl: './page-film.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./page-film.component.scss']
})
export class PageFilmComponent {
 public animated: boolean = true;

 constructor() {
   setTimeout(() => {
    this.animated = false;
   }, 8000);
 } 
}
```

Comment: Where does this play? For your end users, your server starting shouldn't be a thing? Is this playing hen it automatically opens a browser window? This needs a bit more clarification...

Comment: Yes, once the browser opens I'd like to launch the animation. and then my page appears

Comment: Will this happen every time you launch the page? Or only "when your server started",, because it's that requirement that I am hanging on (it seems useless to implement as it would be a lot of code with the server storing something in the session for every user on startup or something)

Comment: the animation should start each time the page is launched

Comment: So, your codepen is already doing that on launch, so yeah, just serve this and run it on something like page load?

Answer (score 0):

If you are really waiting for the server to start up, well that's a bit complicated. But if you just want to show animation before bootstrapping the application, you can do it by placing the animation HTML & CSS into the **index.html** file.

It's better to do it here, because it will prevent any strange fragments or flickering. If you think about it, it's not really the Angular stuff, animation is something which should occur before Angular takes place.

Index.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My app</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    // Paste you animation style here
  </style>
  <body>

    <!-- Component you are bootstrapping -->
    <app-component>
      <!-- Place the animation HTML inside your app-component -->
      <!-- Once the Angular is ready, it'll be removed -->
      <div id="container">
        <!-- Edit the letter attr to: N, E, T, F, L, I or X -->
        <netflixintro letter="N">
          <!-- ... -->
        </netflixintro>
      </div>
    </app-component>

  </body>
</html>
```

Now, in order to see the full animation, you have to implement the APP_INITIALIZER which postpones the bootstrapping of the Angular application.

```typescript
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [ /* ... */ ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    SomeService
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInit,
      //deps: [SomeService], // only if needed
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And your appInit can look like this

```typescript
import { map, timer } from 'rxjs';

// Waits for 8000 ms and then emits true
// Adjust the time so that the whole animation is played
export function appInit(someService: SomeService): () => Observable<boolean> {
  // In case you provided a service in `deps`, you can get it as a function param
  return () => timer(8000).pipe(map(() => true))
}
```

`appInit` function can be provided with service, which you can use to check, if server is running and only then emit true. Of course, in such case you should also wait for the animation timer to finish.